# How to remove nodes of HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if I'm doing this as well as it can be done and if anyone has a better way, please let me know.

I have a table of data that's pushed onto a page with AJAX. The user has the option of deleting these data. If there are no more data to delete, I want the row to be removed from the list.

I'm not sure how, and would like to know if I can remove a row of data with no id attached to the row itself.

Here is what one of the table rows of data looks like

```
<tr>
  <td data-pid="2"><a data-pid="2" href="#">test</a></td>
  <td><a data-pid="2" class="manage-icon" href="#"><img alt="" src="delete.png"></a></td>
</tr>

This is what I'm using to get the id
$(this).attr('data-pid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('a[data-pid="' + pid + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

use

```
$(this).data('pid');
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr('data-pid');
```

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

`.parents()` for all matching ancestor elements.

`closest()` for the first closest matching element (either an ancestor or self).

`.closest()` is better and faster in your case

Comment: Thank you Tushar. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the pointer on using `data()`! That is good to know

Comment: isn't possible to select tr or td using jquery...

for me `$('tr')`... isn't working

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yes you can select any element by tagname `$('tr')` will refer to all `tr` tags in the page read here --? http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove that tr?

```
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        var a = $(this).parent();
        if(confirm('Delete?')) {
            var pid = a.data('pid');
            //do ajax remove;
            a.parents('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess I wouldn't really have to worry about the semantics of leaving an empty `<tr>` tag if I used this, right?

Comment: I think this is what I'm going for here. I want to remove the entire row the user clicks on but I'm having an issue because there is no id attached to the row. But, I see that `$(this).parent('tr').remove();` may do it for me. I'll give this a try. Thank you

Comment: it's `parents('tr')`, not `parent`, it was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to get this working. The thing is.. there are two divs, one on the left and one on the right. The initial list I'm trying to delete from is the one on the left but it's based on the user deleting rows on the right div. Is there a way that I can reference the div on the left?

Comment: You need to show more code, I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: OK, I got it. Tushar's example worked. Thank you very much for helping me and seeing me through this.